# How does RMI implements the distributed system's single image appearance to end user

Tags: rmi, distributed-system

We bind Server's name with it's object in rmi registry.And then look up the registry by the server's name or address.How does this keep the distributed System's single image intact as a user must not care about from where the data comes?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by 'the distributed system's single image', but the object you lookup in the Registry can be located anywhere, not just in the host containing the Registry. Although putting it somewhere else does take a little more work.

Comment: I meant the user does not know from which node data comes in a distributed system. So since the servers are distributed and different,how does user know which server contains the data?

Comment: He only has to know where the Registry is. After that it's all automatic.